# C++ Increase Atomic Float

Tags: c++, multithreading, floating-point, c++20, stdatomic

I have a `std::atomic<float>` that I would like to increment by a certain value. However, using `fetch_add()` on an `atomic<float>` does not compile and does not seem to be allowed. Is there anyway I can get around this? Here is the code snippet I tried:

```
std::atomic<float> data(0);
void do_work(){ data.fetch_add(1); }
```

The error I get is that `fetch_add` is not a member of `atomic<float>`

**EDIT**: Forgot to clarify that I am compiling with g++ version 9.3.0 using `-std=c++2a`

Comment: It says you need c++20 for that here [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add)

Comment: Yes, I am compiling with -std=c++2a. gcc version 9.3.0 btw. I'll clarify in the post

Comment: Seems to work fine with g++ 10: https://godbolt.org/z/Th5qeK.  It may simply have not yet been implemented for g++ 9.

Comment: I used the link from @NateEldredge saw it working at g++-10.0 and switched to 9.3 and got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point atomics are only supported by the C++ library in g++ 10.1 and later.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html and search for `P0020R6`.

Your code compiles fine with g++ 10.2: [Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Th5qeK)